# Why do you need serial port connection between QEMU guest and host?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am new to qemu. I was exploring some commands to setup qemu VM. Can someone please explain why serial ports are required/desired between guest and the host? Also, what does '-serial pty' and -'serial mon:stdio' mean?

Answer (score 1):

A serial console allows you to connect to your VM using tools such as `screen` or`minicom`, typically to debug your kernel when doing system development, or simply to have an additional console while running a Unix-like OS.

Using 'mon:stdio' allows you to send commands alternatively to qemu itself and to the serial console. See [these examples.](https://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/qemu-command-line-behavior-of-serial-stdio-vs-serial-monstdio/) This is mostly useful for system debugging.

If you're running your VM using *libvirt* and *kvm*, a serial console allows you to connect to a Unix-like VM directly from `virsh`, for instance when a VM network isn't properly set up.